# How to verify ownership of a Google Apps Script in Webmaster

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, google-search-console

I am trying to write a script and use it as a Webhook listener for gmail pub/sub notifications.

Therefore, I would need to verify the domain associated with the script in domain verification in API&Services.

However, a modal asks me to verify the domain's ownership on webmaster.

I have tried to add the `google-site-verification` using the following dotGet function in google apps script and can see the tag in the head:

`function doGet(e) { return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setTitle("Hello World").addMetaTag('google-site-verification', 'verification-code'); }`

However, the Webmaster verification does not go through and it shows that it found a different verification code.

Comment: Related [Unable to create subscription with a push end point on App Script (script.google.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30584533/1595451), [google apps script web app verify ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13807162/1595451)

Comment: The different code is because it accesses `/exec/` instead of `/exec`. The former redirects to a accounts.google.com for sign in